# Python: Finding the value of a key with a variable assigned that key

Tags: python, dictionary, key

This is worded terribly but I'm very new to coding, here is an example of what I want to do:

```
import random  
dict={
'option1': 1,
'option2': 2,
}
randomDictionaryChoice=random.choice(list(dict.keys()))
valueOfThatKey=dict.get('randomDictionaryChoice')
print(valueOfThatKey)
```

At the moment it prints "none" instead of 1 or 2.

This is likely structured badly or bad ettiquette so feel free to comment on that too. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have quotes around `'randomDictionaryChoice'`, so it's looking for an entry in the dict with that literal word as the key (which doesn't exist). Remove the quotes:

```
>>> valueOfThatKey=dict.get(randomDictionaryChoice)
>>> print(valueOfThatKey)
2
```

(also -- you should avoid using the names of builtins like `dict`, `list`, or `string` for variable names)

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a new error, I'll see if I can handle this one now haha.

Answer (score 2):

You have no `'randomDictionaryChoice'` key, indeed. Pass in the variable, not a string:

```
valueOfThatKey = somedict.get(randomDictionaryChoice)
```

Note that you shouldn't `dict` to name your dictionary, as that masks the built-in type.

If you don't need the key, you could just pick directly from `dict.values()`:

```
random_value = random.choice(list(somedict.values()))
```

Comment: Thanks! I need the key as it's a pack of cards in blackjack so i have it set up as '7 of hearts':10, 'jack of hearts': 10 etc. There might be a better way of doing this if you can think?

Comment: @JoeJenkins: Why do you have a dictionary in the first place then? Just have a list of `Card` instances and use `random.choice()` directly on that list?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Sorry?

Comment: @JoeJenkins: I'm not sure why you need a dictionary to track a set of cards?

Comment: I want to say to the person the key ie, jack of diamonds, 8 of hearts or king of clubs, but keep track of their values- so jack is 10, 8 is 8 and king is 10